# IPython error executing system commands

Tags: ipython

If I execute any system commend in ipython2/3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I get permission denied error as follows:

```
In [1]: ls
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5b21b94dda0e> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('ls ')
```

I did not need to do anything special in Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed ipython2 and ipython3 with

```
pip2 install ipython --user
pip3 install ipython --user
```

I also tried installing it system-wide with `sudo` as

```
sudo pip2 install ipython
sudo pip3 install ipython
```

But the problem still persists. I do not get this problem in jupyter notebook.

How can I use system commands in IPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was setting up my machine, I created a dummy rootUser as the first *admin* user. Later on, I created another user with the same *name*, *uid* and *gid* as my workplace and added it to *sudo*. This some how causes permission problems which is really strange. Though I do not know the actual cause of the problem but I did reproduce it with the above steps. I solved this problem by creating the first user with the name same as my workplace. Later i changed the *uid* and *gid* and file/directly permissions accordingly. This solved the problem and I can now use ipython2/3 normally.

Answer (score 0):

As written in [ipython docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html?highlight=!ls) - You should prefix the command with `!`

e.g. for `ls` you should execute `!ls`

> String lists (IPython.utils.text.SList) are handy way to process
>   output from system commands. They are produced by var = !cmd syntax.
>
> First, we acquire the output of ‘ls -l’:
>
> ```
> [Q:doc/examples]|2> lines = !ls -l
>  ==
> ['total 23',
>  '-rw-rw-rw- 1 ville None 1163 Sep 30  2006 example-demo.py',
>  '-rw-rw-rw- 1 ville None 1927 Sep 30  2006 example-embed-short.py',
>  '-rwxrwxrwx 1 ville None 4606 Sep  1 17:15 example-embed.py',
>  '-rwxrwxrwx 1 ville None 1017 Sep 30  2006 example-gnuplot.py',
>  '-rwxrwxrwx 1 ville None  339 Jun 11 18:01 extension.py',
>  '-rwxrwxrwx 1 ville None  113 Dec 20  2006 seteditor.py',
>  '-rwxrwxrwx 1 ville None  245 Dec 12  2006 seteditor.pyc']
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Yaron for quick response, however, it gives same error even with how you suggested. By the way, if you execute ls command, do you also see error? In my case on Ubuntu 14.04 and on another system with Ubuntu 16.04 I do not get error even with plain ls command. Only on my laptop I see this error and i have no clue why ....